# How can i convert gis (georeferenced) multi-polygons annotation to another format?

Tags: python, deep-learning, qgis, semantic-segmentation, pyqgis

is there any method to convert georeferenced polygons (annotation done by qgis) to another format (coco, yolo..), so i can train models for object segmentation ? Then re-convert the model outputs to georeferenced polygons so i can re-import them to qgis ?

Comment: it's all flat planes, right? there's nothing special to do. all the deep learning just assumes images with square pixels, and the annotations are either in pixels or normalized to width and height, i.e. values from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: of course nothing in ML understands GIS-specific formats. you'll just need to get the picture, then get the annotations into the local reference frame of the picture. -- disclaimer: I am not a GIS person. messing around with openstreetmap pseudo-mercator hardly qualifies me.

Comment: "you'll just need to get the picture, then get the annotations into the local reference frame of the picture." 
That's exactly what i'm looking for ! Is there any python package to do the transformation ?

Comment: not being a GIS person, I can't answer that. I imagine that GIS packages have that capability. pick any *map projection*, then project both the picture and the points/polygon into the map. I'd recommend something that doesn't distort too wildly. transverse mercator seems good, or perspective/orthogonal projection of sphere/spheroid/ellipsoid/... surface?